# How to base 64 encode a dataframe in r

Tags: r, base64, github-api

As an example lets take `df <- head(iris)`. How would I encode this into a base64 string. I need it for the GitHub API content argument.

At the moment I have been trying to use the `base64encode()` function but get the *"error in normalizePath"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for the GitHub API after some research the following code worked perfectly as it was able to decode and move the table to Github:

```
df1<-charToRaw(paste(capture.output(write.table(Table, quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE , sep=",")), collapse="\n")) 

base64_code<-base64enc::base64encode(df1)
```

This was able to be placed in the content argument of the rest API to update the file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `serialize` to get the raw bytes of the object and convert them to base 64:

```r
df <- head(iris)
b64_string <- base64enc::base64encode(serialize(df, NULL))

b64_string
#> [1] "WAoAAAADAAMGAgADBQAAAAAGQ1AxMjUyAAADEwAAAAUAAAAOAAAABkAUZmZmZmZ
#>      mQBOZmZmZmZpAEszMzMzMzUASZmZmZmZmQBQAAAAAAABAFZmZmZmZmgAAAA4AAAA
#>      GQAwAAAAAAABACAAAAAAAAEAJmZmZmZmaQAjMzMzMzM1ADMzMzMzMzUAPMzMzMzM
#>      zAAAADgAAAAY/9mZmZmZmZj/2ZmZmZmZmP/TMzMzMzM0/+AAAAAAAAD/2ZmZmZmZ
#>      mP/szMzMzMzMAAAAOAAAABj/JmZmZmZmaP8mZmZmZmZo/yZmZmZmZmj/JmZmZmZm
#>      aP8mZmZmZmZo/2ZmZmZmZmgAAAw0AAAAGAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAA
#>      BAAAEAgAAAAEABAAJAAAABmxldmVscwAAABAAAAADAAQACQAAAAZzZXRvc2EABAA
#>      JAAAACnZlcnNpY29sb3IABAAJAAAACXZpcmdpbmljYQAABAIAAAABAAQACQAAAAV
#>      jbGFzcwAAABAAAAABAAQACQAAAAZmYWN0b3IAAAD+AAAEAgAAAAEABAAJAAAABW5
#>      hbWVzAAAAEAAAAAUABAAJAAAADFNlcGFsLkxlbmd0aAAEAAkAAAALU2VwYWwuV2l
#>      kdGgABAAJAAAADFBldGFsLkxlbmd0aAAEAAkAAAALUGV0YWwuV2lkdGgABAAJAAA
#>      AB1NwZWNpZXMAAAQCAAAAAQAEAAkAAAAJcm93Lm5hbWVzAAAADQAAAAKAAAAAAAA
#>      ABgAABAIAAAL/AAAAEAAAAAEABAAJAAAACmRhdGEuZnJhbWUAAAD+"
```

You can undo this operation after transmission with:

```r
unserialize(base64enc::base64decode(b64_string))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

However, if this is for github, it may be best to transmit the code that reproduces the data frame rather than binary information. This can be achieved with `dput`, e.g.

```r
ascii_string <- paste(capture.output(dput(df)), collapse = "\n")

ascii_string
#> [1] "structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), \n    
#> Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, \n    
#> 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, \n    0.2, 0.2, 
#> 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, \n    1L), .Label = 
#> c(\"setosa\", \"versicolor\", \"virginica\"), class = \"factor\")), 
#> row.names = c(NA, \n6L), class = \"data.frame\")"
```

This could be written to a .R file as a way of reproducing the data frame. It can also be used to reconstitute the data frame programatically with `eval(parse(text = ascii_string))`

Comment: The GitHub API only allows base64 encoded content, therefore the first option worked. However, the API was not able to decode it on its own as it required to be unserialized.